# Why does fixed point iteration have to be in radians?

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

This might seem like a dumb question but I can't find an explanation anywahere.

I was working on this problem:

> Apply the fixed-point iteration method to this function
>   $$f(x)=2(\sin x+\cos x)−x$$
>   with $x_1=2$

I rearranged the equation into an "fixed point equation":

$$f(x)=0\Rightarrow f(x)=2(\sin{x}+\cos{x})−x=0$$
$$x=2(\sin{⁡x}+\cos{⁡x})$$
$$\frac{x}{2}=\sin⁡{x}+\cos⁡{x}$$
$$x=\sin{x}+\cos{x}+\frac{x}{2}$$
$$g(x)=x⇒g(x)=\sin x+\cos x+\frac{x}{2}$$

I iterated a sufficient amount of times to find $ x \approx 1.71$

I had done all of the above in radians for simplicity however when I tried it with my calculator working in degrees and $$r=2, x=2.034$$

I iterated a sufficient amount of times to find $ x \approx 2.71$
which differs from the radians answer by 1. This seems suspicious as the real convergence does go to $x \approx 1.71$, why can (or can't if I'm wrong) fixed point only be in radians? and why was my degrees result exactly 1 greater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What **definition** of trig functions (also called "circular functions") are you using?

The definitions in terms of right angles cannot be used in general as that requires the angle to be between 0 and 90 degrees but, in order to use them as **functions** we want them defined for all real numbers.

Of the "circle" definition is used:  Construct a unit circle (center at (0, 0), radius 1) in an xy-coordinate system.  Given non-negative number, t, measure, counter clockwise, around the circumference a distance t (for negative t, measure clockwise).  The endpoint has coordinates $(\cos(t), \sin(t))$.  That is, whatever the end point is, the x coordinate is, by definition, $\cos(t)$, the y coordinate is $\sin(t)$.

Notice that "$t$" is NOT in degrees because it is not an angle at all, it is a distance around the circumference.  We can think of that as an angle by identifying the angle with the distance subtended on a unit circle which is simply the **definition** of "radian".

Comment: thank you for the answer, i looked at your answer in edit mode but i cant find it, why is it like a scroll wheel??

Answer (score 1):

Yo can also find the solution in degrees if you make a change of variables:
$$x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{180}y$$

But you have to change all $x$ not only in the trigonometric functions. That is probably the reason you can not reach the same result seeking the root in radians or degrees.

equation in degrees:
$$2\left[\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{180}y\right)}+\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{180}y\right)}\right]-\frac{\pi}{180}y=0$$

Comment: okay, i just tried it out and i cant seem to make it work if i set $x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{180}y$ in the first iteration can i then use the answer for the next iteration, or do have to use $\frac{\pi\mbox{answer}}{180}$ both aren't working for me at the moment

Comment: Your new equation is a function of a new variable (in degrees) $y$. Please write the equation to solve as a fixed point: $$y=\frac{360}{\pi}\left[\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{180}y\right)}+\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{180}y\right)}\right]$$ and solve for $y$ with a seed for example $y^0=0$